# access denied for user 'root' even though I can login from terminal, credentials are correct in .env

Tags: mysql

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I can access with root to mysql, can't access from symfony at all, the credentials are correct.

I am going crazy.

tried all grants

mysql version 5.7
and running terminal from localhost not remote.

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Start with a description of your end goal -- what are you trying to do here? Then explain how you're trying to do it, and why, specifically, that's not working. You've got part of that already (about half of #2 and all of #3) but to make this a good question, it needs all three parts.

Comment: Please edit the post and let us k now which MySQL version and OS. Please also reproduce the login via terminal. Are you running the session (in the terminal) locally  in the database machine or from a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

the reason was because mysql_validate_password was enabled, if you tried everything try running mysql> uninstall plugin validate_password;